# webpack style-loader displays css as a base64 encoded string inside the style tag

Tags: javascript, css, django, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I am using the style-loader to load css. But the css displays as a base64 encoded string as follows:

```
<style type="text/css">
data:text/css;base64,dmFyIgvZ......
    many lines
</style>
```

The same bundle.js seems to work correctly inside an almost empty index.html. In this case it displays the CSS as a proper string.

What am I doing wrong?

My webpack.config.js:

```
rules: [
  { test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'url-loader', 'css-loader' ]
  },
```

Comment: how do you load this css file?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Have added relevant portions of my webpack.config.js.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove url-loader from the list of loaders.